# Executing a query in a specific hour

Tags: php, mysql

I have `script` that run a `php` every minute. I want to make a variable that store the current hour everytime its runs so i can make an `if()` statement so when its 7pm execute the code inside.

```
$hour = date('H');
If($hour >= 7:00pm <= 5:00am)
{Do something that i know how to do it xD}
```

Please no Cron Job or similar.

Comment: try to add some code that produces the case, we can dscuss starting from that point

Comment: You'd do better to set up a cron job (*nix) or a scheduled task (Windows).  That's exactly the type of thing they do best.

Comment: What is the Javascript tag for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Miguel
By default, PHP took the time from server where its located. You can set the default time in your common PHP file(which includes in all pages or at-least in that page, in which you wrote the code to execute).
using the below function, you can set the default time zone for your web application.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

here is the list of Timezones (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), select according to your desire country/city and pass that value in the above function.

Answer (score 1):

`date('H');` will return the current hour.

You can then use it in an `if`-statement.

It is hard to provide more than this as you showed very little of how and why you want to perform this check.

Comment: Its give me 04? Its 11pm in my timezone.

Comment: @MiguelAngel it is based on what `php.ini` says. If you don't want leading `0` change to `G` instead of `H`.

Comment: Ok i get it but the hour is not in my timezone. I live in Puerto Rico... (UTC -04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this might be handled better via a cron. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, something rather alternative that might be a better solution depending on what you are trying to do, is to just setup the script to run everyday at 7PM. 
This can be done via cron jobs in linux with the following command:

```
0 18 * * * php -q /path/to/php/script.php
```

This will be based on your server time and timezone. Based on your comment on Emz's post, You should know that when you track the time with php you need to realize that php.ini can change the time in php scripts as it has it's own timezone!